# Get the width of the cell in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

This might be a simple question, but I have searched for hours but was unable to find the answer.

Is there a way to get the cell width in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method of the UITableView?

The reason is that I need to calculate the height of a NSAttributedString using `boundingRectWithSize` and constraint it to the width of the cell.

Currently I am calculating it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and then reloading the row.

This is causing each row to refresh after calculating its height which is not a very good user experience.

So can I get the width of the cell in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I assume your cells are the same width as the `UITableView` they are in. Therefore, just use `_tableView.frame.size.width` to get your answer.

Comment: @msg Not if in a grouped table view on <iOS 7

Comment: the groupd tableview is 20 shorter according to the tableview :)

Comment: @adali On the iPad, the cells in a grouped table may have more padding depending on the width of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of `UITableView`, Grouped, and Plain.

Grouped table views have cells which are smaller than the width of the table view meaning that you should find the width in your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method by running an `NSLog` i.e. `NSLog(@"%f", cell.contentView.frame.size.width);`. You can then use this to determine the height.

Plain table views have cells which have the same width as the `UITableView`, and therefore, you can use the width of the table view i.e `self.tableView.frame.size.width`.

More can be found here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You can't always determine a cell's width in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. If you are dealing with a new cell not yet added to the table view, the cell's `contentView` may not yet be sized. And it is worse for grouped tables because the padding of the grouped cell can vary (on the iPad at least depending on the width of the table view).

Comment: @rmaddy what do you suggest? It could be worth checking the origin of the label and suggesting a viable width for the text label / working it out by setting a large string as the label's text?

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `layoutSubviews`

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell

@end

@implementation MyCell 

-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // You can get the width here using self.bounds.size.width
}

@end
```

As msgambel suggested, if you're using `UITableViewStylePlain` then just the table's width is fine. However if you're doing anything complicated within the cell, subclassing is a good idea.

Comment: This helped me with setting a constraint in the cell that had to do with the cell width, in cellForRowAtIndexpath i got the nib width of the cell not the actual width, setting constraints there broke my constraint. So this is the way to go 4 me. Thanx Khan :)